# Perform operation on first element and then all items of list in java stream

Tags: list, java-8, stream, java-stream

I want to iterate a list of object 2 times. First time I need to use only first object and perform some operation. Second time I want to perform operation on all the items of list.

In below example, I have list of TestPojo i.e. testPojoList.

Using Java stream I have tried to achieve the same in 2 steps (Operation#1 and Operation#2) Is there any better way or I can merge both of the operations in single operation? below is the piece of code:

```
 public void Mapping() {
        TestPojo testPojo1 = TestPojo.builder().name("Mike").city("Denver").company("Tesla").build();
        TestPojo testPojo2 = TestPojo.builder().name("Bob").city("Atlanta").company("Tesla").build();
        TestPojo testPojo3 = TestPojo.builder().name("Steve").city("Chicago").company("Tesla").build();
        TestPojo testPojo4 = TestPojo.builder().name("John").city("Boston").company("Tesla").build();

        List<TestPojo> testPojoList = Arrays.asList(testPojo1, testPojo2, testPojo3, testPojo4);

        //Operation1
        TransformedTestPojo transformedTestPojo = testPojoList.stream().findFirst().map(testPojo -> mapCompanyName(testPojo)).orElse(null);
        //Operation2
        List<PersonalDetails> personalDetailsList = testPojoList.stream().map(testPojo -> mapOtherDetails(testPojo)).collect(Collectors.toList());,
        
        transformedTestPojo.setPersonalDetailsList(personalDetailsList);
        System.out.println(transformedTestPojo);
    }

    private PersonalDetails mapOtherDetails(TestPojo testPojo) {
        return PersonalDetails.builder().name(testPojo.getName()).City(testPojo.getCity()).build();
    }

    private TransformedTestPojo mapCompanyName(TestPojo testPojo) {
        return TransformedTestPojo.builder().company(testPojo.getCompany()).build();
    }

public class TestPojo {
    String name;
    String city;
    String company;
}

public class TransformedTestPojo {
    String company;
    List<PersonalDetails> personalDetailsList;
}

public class PersonalDetails {
    String name;
    String City;
}
```

Following will be the output:

```
//Request List
{
    "testPojoList": [
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "city": "Denver",
            "company": "Tesla"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "city": "Atlanta",
            "company": "Tesla"
        },
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "city": "Chicago",
            "company": "Tesla"
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "city": "Boston",
            "company": "Tesla"
        }
    ]
}

//Response Object
"TransformedTestPojo":
{
    "company": "Tesla",
    "personalDetailsList": [
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "City": "Denver"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "City": "Atlanta"
        },
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "City": "Chicago"
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "City": "Boston"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code.  Please explain what you want to do. Also include examples of before and after data as well as any class definitions.

Comment: @WJS I have given my problem statement at the beginning (before code snippet). Updated the expected request and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. But first, I created the classes.  Instead of a builder I used a constructor for `TestPojo`. But it will still work.

```
class TestPojo {
    String name;
    String city;
    String company;
    
    public TestPojo(String name, String city, String company) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.company = company;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s, %s]", name, city, company);
    }
    
}

class TransformedTestPojo {
    String company;
    List<PersonalDetails> personalDetailsList;
    
    public TransformedTestPojo(String company,
            List<PersonalDetails> personalDetailsList) {
        this.company = company;
        this.personalDetailsList = personalDetailsList;
    }
    
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    
    public List<PersonalDetails> getPersonalDetailsList() {
        return personalDetailsList;
    }
    
}

class PersonalDetails {
    String name;
    String City;
    
    public PersonalDetails(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        City = city;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", name, City);
    }   
}
```

**The Data**

```
List<TestPojo> testPojoList =
        List.of(new TestPojo("Mike", "Denver", "Tesla"),
                new TestPojo("Bob", "Atlanta", "Tesla"),
                new TestPojo("Steve", "Chicago", "Tesla"),
                new TestPojo("John", "Boston", "Tesla"));
```

**The Map approach using a loop**

The best approach (imo) is to use Java 8 features of the `Map` interface

- allocate a map
- Iterate over the `testPojoList`
- `Map.compute` will take a key, and then if the value is null, create one.  Otherwise, it uses the existing value.
- that value is returned and can be used in the same construct to further modify the value.  In this case it does the following:

  - create a new `TransformedTestPojo` instance with the `key (company)` and new `ArrayList<>()` for the personal details.
  - then return that list and get the personal details list and add a new Personal details instance.

```
Map<String, TransformedTestPojo> map = new HashMap<>();

for (TestPojo tp : testPojoList) {
    map.compute(tp.getCompany(),
            (k, v) -> v == null ? new TransformedTestPojo(k,
                    new ArrayList<>()) : v)
            .getPersonalDetailsList().add(new PersonalDetails(
                    tp.getName(), tp.getCity()));
}
```

Once the map has been created, get the map values (which has the `TransformedTestPojo` instances) and return as a collection.

```
Collection<TransformedTestPojo> collection = map.values();
```

Note that a Collection (super type of List) , not a List is created. If a list is required you can do the following.

```
 List<TransformedTestPojo> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

**Displaying the results**

```
list.forEach(k -> {
    System.out.println(k.getCompany());
    k.getPersonalDetailsList()
            .forEach(p -> System.out.println("     " + p));
});
```

prints

```
Tesla
     [Mike, Denver]
     [Bob, Atlanta]
     [Steve, Chicago]
     [John, Boston]
```

**Here is a stream solution.**

- stream the testPojoList
- Use `Collectors.groupingBy` with company as the key
- The associated list will be of `PersonalDetails` instances.
- then stream the `entrySet` of the `map` and build a list of `TransformedTestPojo`

```
List<TransformedTestPojo> list1 = testPojoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestPojo::getCompany,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        tp -> new PersonalDetails(
                                tp.getName(), tp.getCity()),
                        Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new TransformedTestPojo(e.getKey(),
                e.getValue()))
        .toList();
}
```

Note that the map itself could be used instead of a returned `List<TransformedTestPojo>`.  The `key` is the `company name` and the value contains the list of `PersonalDetails`.  If that is useful, then all you need is the following:

```
Map<String, List<PersonalDetails>> result = testPojoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestPojo::getCompany,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        tp -> new PersonalDetails(
                                tp.getName(), tp.getCity()),
                        Collectors.toList())))
```